# Fax pdf attachments are being stripped when forwarding or replying

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a problem in Outlook. When the clients send a fax to us they get emailed to outlook in pdf format. And when any user tries to forward these emails with attachment, the attachment gets stripped out and Chinese letters are added in the body. Where as the regular pdf attachments sent from Outlook or Gmail seem to work fine when they are forwarded or replied to.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Should we infer the same happens when using (web) Gmail? If so, definitely there's something weird with that "fax as PDF" attachment, either a bug or a feature. A workaround would be saving that attachment and composing a new mail with it instead of forwarding.

Comment: As of now I have advised users to use "Forward as Attachment" option since saving this attachment and then reattaching to new email would be time consuming.. When I use Outlook on web the attachment is added and also in safe mode it works as intended. This is limited to Outlook desktop application.

Comment: Ok as an workaround. And with that clarification it's something related to the Outlook client only. Perhaps it need updates or patches.

Comment: Yes. I searched on Microsoft forums for the updates, but to no avail. We are using Microsoft Office Standard 2016, I'd appreciate if you could advise me where exactly to fetch the updates. Thank You.

Comment: Since you're already using a current version I have no suggestions.